# OkHttp3 cache seems to be unchecked with Retrofit 2

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to setup an HTTP cache using Retrofit (2.1.0) and OkHttp (3.3.1). I have seen many posts related to this topic, but none of them helped.

I wrote some unit tests to see how the cache works. It works just fine, but once integrated in my app, the magic ends. I will first show you my implementation and then explain some of my investigation.

First, here is my Retrofit instantiation :

```
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);

    OkHttpClient client = httpBuilder
            .addNetworkInterceptor(INTERCEPTOR_RESPONSE_SET_CACHE)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(INTERCEPTOR_REQUEST_ADD_CHECKSUM)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .cache(cacheHttpClient).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build();
```

Here is the interceptor adding a header to set cache control:

```
    private final Interceptor INTERCEPTOR_RESPONSE_SET_CACHE = new Interceptor() {

        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            response = response.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=600") //+ Integer.toString(3600 * 5)
                    .build();
            return response;
        }
    };
```

The last interceptor adds 2 URL parameters:

```
 private static final Interceptor INTERCEPTOR_REQUEST_ADD_CHECKSUM = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
            HttpUrl url = chain.request().url();
            url = url.newBuilder().addQueryParameter("rd", "random1").addQueryParameter("chk","check1").build();
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().url(url).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    };
```

Finally, the single method of my service :

```
 @Headers("Cache-Control: public, max-stale=500")
 @GET("/get_data")
 Call<DataResponse> getData(@Query("year") int year, @Query("month") int month, @Query("day") int day);
```

About my investigation, I setup an interceptor logger (app side, not network) to see what is happening. I can see lines such as "Cache-Control: public, max-stale=500" in my logs. This means (at least to me) that the header should give an opportunity to the OkHttp client to check the cache.

The cache itself seems to be correctly initialised. When I create it, I force the initialisation and log all the urls present in the cache. Here is how it is implemented:

```
File httpCacheDirectory = new File(getCacheDir(), "responses");
        httpCacheDirectory.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
        Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize);
        try {
            cache.initialize();
            Iterator<String> iterator = cache.urls();
            Log.i(TAG, "URLs in cacheHttpClient : ");
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Log.i(TAG, iterator.next());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i(TAG, "CACHE NOT INIT");
        }
```

When I launch my app with Wifi available, I get the expected responses. Then I kill my app, disable Wifi and relaunch the app. I expect the cache to serve data at this moment. But it fails and I can only see OkHttp printed lines in logs :

> HTTP FAILED: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
>   "my-domain.com": No address associated with hostname

Last thing, in [RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3), one can read :

> max-stale : Indicates that the client is willing to accept a response
>   that has exceeded its expiration time. If max-stale is assigned a
>   value, then the client is willing to accept a response that has
>   exceeded its expiration time by no more than the specified number of
>   seconds. If no value is assigned to max-stale, then the client is
>   willing to accept a stale response of any age.

When I don't specify an value, it actually works (I get a response even when the Wifi is down). For now this is the only way I found to make it "work". So maybe I just misunderstand the cache-control directive !?

At this point I'm really confused. I really would like to be able to use OkHttp cache system, but somehow I'm missing something.

Thank you for reading all that text !

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to create cached okkhttpclient

```
private OkHttpClient createCachedClient(final Context context) {
        File httpCacheDirectory = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "cache_file");

        Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, 20 * 1024 * 1024);
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.setCache(cache);
        okHttpClient.interceptors().add(
                new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
                        String cacheHeaderValue = isOnline(context)
                                ? "public, max-age=2419200"
                                : "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=2419200" ;
                        Request request = originalRequest.newBuilder().build();
                        com.squareup.okhttp.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                        return response.newBuilder()
                                .removeHeader("Pragma")
                                .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
                                .header("Cache-Control", cacheHeaderValue)
                                .build();
                    }
                }
        );
        okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(
                new Interceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
                        String cacheHeaderValue = isOnline(context)
                                ? "public, max-age=2419200"
                                : "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=2419200" ;
                        Request request = originalRequest.newBuilder().build();
                        com.squareup.okhttp.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
                        return response.newBuilder()
                                .removeHeader("Pragma")
                                .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
                                .header("Cache-Control", cacheHeaderValue)
                                .build();
                    }
                }
        );
        return okHttpClient;
    }

    private boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
        }
        return false;


        }
```

Call createCachedClient() method to create OkHttpClient add this client to retrofit

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = createCachedClient(MainActivity.this);
Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
         .client(okHttpClient)
         .baseUrl(API)
         .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory
         .create()).build();
```

Add this permission to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

If internet is available first time it will call the service and cache the request,next time onwards upto 2419200 milliseconds it will use cache to give response.it won't hit server upto 2419200 milliseconds even if device if offline.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I would like Retrofit to check the cache, no matter the current network state. Retrofit should always check the cache first, and return its content in case it's still valid. Or simply try to fetch the content, no matter the network state (because I guess that the result in case of failure is not cached).

Comment: This will do the samething.Only first time it will hit server after that every time it will check cache.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same error `UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host` but it looks like this error appears because of the cache itself: I have this error `remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.myapp/cache/cache_file/journal.tmp` just before the UnknownHostException.

Comment: @Bogy I usually got UnknownHostException when there is no Internet connection and the DNS resolution fails. You should make sure the directory in which the journal file is created exists, otherwise the journal file can't be created.

Comment: I have created the folder and the journal "manually" (I thought `File httpCacheDirectory = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "cache_file"); Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, 20 * 1024 * 1024);` would create automatically. So now I don't have the `remove failed: ENOENT`error but I still got UnknownHostException.

Comment: And if there is no internet connection, why does the cache isn't retuned?

Comment: In your request Header, you can try to add "Cache-Control: public, max-stale". It will only check the server if no response in cache exists. But it's really a plaster, not a solution, as you don't control the cache validity (Hence my original post, for which I still don't have a viable solution).

Comment: It's not working :/ I have opened a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573748/caching-error-with-retrofit-2-and-okhttp-3#41589754) yesterday. Maybe I'm missing something